# Potential function for conservative internal forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, potential, potential-energy

In Goldstein's Classical Mechanics book, he considered a system of particles and looked at  the conservative internal force between particle $i$ and particle $j$ that satisfy the strong law of action and reaction.

He wrote the potential function for this internal force as 
$$V_{ij}=V_{ij}(|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|) .$$

He then said that the forces $\vec{F}_{ji}$ (force particle j exerts on i)  and  $\vec{F}_{ij}$ (force particle i exerts on j) are automatically equal and opposite:

$$\vec{F}_{ji} = - \nabla_i V_{ij}(|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|) = + \nabla_j V_{ij}(|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|) =-\vec{F}_{ij} .$$

I have some problems seeing why $$- \nabla_i V_{ij}(|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|) = + \nabla_j V_{ij}(|\vec{r_i}-\vec{r_j}|). $$The gradient operator acts on different indices, why does a change of sign makes them equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically is just the chain rule?
Since

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec{r}_i}V_{ij}(\vert \vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\vert)&=\dfrac{\partial  V_{ij}}{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}\dfrac{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}{\partial \vec{r}_i}\\
&=\dfrac{\partial  V_{ij}}{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}(1-\delta_{ji})
\end{align}

$$$$

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec{r}_j}V_{ij}(\vert \vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\vert)&=\dfrac{\partial  V_{ij}}{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}\dfrac{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}{\partial \vec{r}_j}\\&=\dfrac{\partial  V_{ij}}{\partial (\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j)}(\delta_{ij}-1)\\&=-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \vec{r}_i}V_{ij}(\vert \vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j\vert)
\end{align}

As far as $\delta_{ij}=\delta_{ji}.$

Comment: Can you explain why you replaced $\nabla_i$ with $\partial \over {\partial \vec{r}_i}$? My understanding is that $\nabla_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \vec{i } + \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \vec{j } + \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} \vec{k }   $

Comment: Your understanding is correct. It is an equivalent notation, but I thought it might help to see the property.